# NoMethodError in Ruby with Comparison Statement

Tags: ruby, comparison-operators

I decided to start learning a bit of Ruby and went to attempt an insertion sort version in Ruby (2.3.0). However when my program checks to see the position and whether to swap values it returns a NoMethodError for '>'. More specifically:

```
./rubyInsertSort.rb:28:in `block in sort': undefined method `>' for 1..4:Range (NoMethodError)
from ./rubyInsertSort.rb:26:in `each'
from ./rubyInsertSort.rb:26:in `sort'
from ./rubyInsertSort.rb:22:in `main'
from ./rubyInsertSort.rb:40:in `<main>'
```

Here is the code for the sorting method:

```
def sort(input, valueAmount)
  for i in 1..valueAmount
    j = i
    while j > 0 and input[j - 1] > input[j]
      input[j], input[j - 1] = input[j - 1], input[j]
      j += -1           
    end
  end

  #Output loop
  for i in 1..valueAmount
    puts "Sort Value #{i} = #{input[i]}"    #Outputs the sorted array to the console
  end
end
```

I know this is probably something trivial and really simple but I can't find a question on here or elsewhere with a solution and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It works fine to me... Try doing it more ruby-wise `(1..valueAmount).each do |i|` and see if it works

Comment: Please give the values of `input` and `valueAmount` that cause this error.

Comment: valueAmount is an integer value that stores the amount of values to store, input is an array of size[valueAmount] that stores the list of values. In this case the input values were: 2, 7, 4, and 9

Comment: @RubyRacer I've tried your fix and now receive a different error upon running

        ../rubyInsertSort.rb:26:in `sort': undefined method `each' for 3:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Comment: I can't replicate your errors. It actually runs fine for me. Your error messages are pretty funky though. The original error says you're trying to use `>` on a range of numbers, but I don't see you doing that in your sort method. Your second error says undefined method `each`. You need to call `each` on an array, and this error usually pops up if you call it on something other than an array or hash. Your solution works, and I can submit a refactored version of it, but I don't know why you're getting these errors. Maybe it has to do with your environment or ruby version?

Comment: I'll have to try it in a different environment tomorrow @philipyoo, the program was just done in Vim and ran using './rubyInsertSort.rb' on Ubuntu. Would using the 'ruby filename' command possibly be a fix?

Comment: I'm not sure how you ran your file, but running `ruby filename` should work.  However, if you're getting error messages, you're definitely running the correct file. Maybe you can copy paste your method into a Ruby repl like irb or pry and try it out again. I've never used vim before so maybe it could be the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your version

```
def sort(input, valueAmount)
  for i in 1...valueAmount  # Added a dot
    j = i
    while j >= 0 and input[j - 1] > input[j]  # >= instead of >
      input[j], input[j - 1] = input[j - 1], input[j]
      j += -1
    end
  end

  #Output loop
  for i in 0...valueAmount  # Added a dot
    puts "Sort Value #{i} = #{input[i]}"    #Outputs the sorted array to the console
  end
end
```

And here is my version (without output)

```
def insertion_sort!(ary)
  return ary if ary.size < 2
  1.upto(ary.size - 1) do |i|
    i.downto(0) do |j|
      break if ary[j - 1] <= ary[j]
      ary[j - 1], ary[j] = ary[j], ary[j - 1]
    end
  end
  ary
end
```

Comment: Your solution appear to have worked for me, thank you for the help!